# jquerymobile panel on swipe not closed properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, panel

If i open right panel and trying to close on swipe page content gets moved and shows white space. in system browser works fine but getting issue on the mobile device.

following code is here:

```
    <a href="#menupanel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon">panel</a>


    <div data-role="panel" id="menupanel" data-theme="a" data-display="overlay" data-dismissible="true">

    <ul data-role="listview">
    <li>Acura</li>
    <li>Audi</li>
    <li>BMW</li>
    <li>Cadillac</li>
    <li>Ferrari</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i don't know what is the issue on the code please help me on that thank in advance

Comment: Can you post the full html of the page? cause the position of panel in your page has significance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your panel inside the content-div just under your regular content.